# Fedex gem, multiples packages

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops

I'm trying to calculate the shipping cost depending of the total quantity of the product purchased with the Fedex gemhttps://github.com/jazminschroeder/fedex. I'm getting the rates but I have different packages options, 3 actually.
the first one when the quantity is 1 (small), the second one when the quantity is 2 (medium) and the third one when the quantity is 3 or 4 (larger).

```
def packages_types
    packages = []
    if @order.quantity >= 4
      packages << { :weight => {:units => "LB", :value => @order.case_weight},
                    :dimensions => {:length => 8, :width => 1, :height => 7, :units => "IN" } }
    elsif @order.quantity == 2
      packages << { :weight => {:units => "LB", :value => 21},
                    :dimensions => {:length => 1, :width => 2, :height => 7, :units => "IN" } }
    elsif @order.quantity == 1
      packages << { :weight => {:units => "LB", :value => 10},
                    :dimensions => {:length => 1, :width => 2, :height => 2, :units => "IN" } }
    end
end
```

So if the client orders 5 on quantity. It's going to be the package of 4(large) and 1 of the small package. I was thinking using the mod...

Comment: What is your issue here?

Comment: The issue is... Depends of the quantity if is more than 4... How to select to use the large package and 1 small package in case the quantity is 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def packages_types
  packages              = []
  extra_items_count     = @order.quantity % 4
  large_packages_needed = (@order.quantity - extra_items_count) / 4

  # point A
  large_packages_needed.times do
    packages << { :weight     => { :units => "LB", :value => @order.case_weight },
                  :dimensions => { :length => 8, :width => 1, :height => 7, :units => "IN" } }
  end

  # point B
  case extra_items_count
  when 1
    packages << { :weight     => { :units => "LB", :value => 10 },
                  :dimensions => { :length => 1, :width => 2, :height => 2, :units => "IN" } }
  when 2
    packages << { :weight     => { :units => "LB", :value => 21 },
                  :dimensions => { :length => 1, :width => 2, :height => 7, :units => "IN" } }
  when 3, 4
    packages << { :weight     => { :units => "LB", :value => @order.case_weight },
                  :dimensions => { :length => 8, :width => 1, :height => 7, :units => "IN" } }
  end

  return packages
end
```

**Point A**: For each group of 4 items, a large package is needed (and added to the `packages` array).

**Point B**: For the remaining items (example: you ordered 5 items -> 1 large package of 4 items + 1 small for 1 remaining item), we add the corresponding conditions in the `package` array.